# Zyxel P-660H-D1

Tags: web-server, zyxel

Can't seem to load the web interface of Zyxel P-660H-D1 ADSL Router, I have to refresh quite a few times and then the web interface appears and sometimes it doesn't.

Also, I can't seem to change the user and Admin password, even when I enter the default password (1234) it won't log-on, but if you don't enter anything and just click login - it will.

anyone with some thoughts on this or faced a similar / same situation with a zyxel.
Have contacted there support but its been 24 hours and no reply as of yet :-)

Will be grateful for your help on this
Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often a firmware upgrade/downgrade helps with these kind of issues.
Also, do you connect over LAN or over ADSL? Maybe poor line quality could be the cause...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am accessing it over the lan it is connected on, can't change password, have to refresh alot to get the interface.

any precautions while upgrading the firmware, as some of these types of routers have two types of firmware file or is it just a case of downloading the firmware and uploading it ?

Thanks

Comment: @rihaturn Just be sure that the firmware is for the *exact* model and for the country you'll use it in.

Comment: MrShunz, Thank you for the reply, during the firmware install process, will it delete all the existing settings ?

I have downloaded the appropriate firmware, is it just a case of pointing the file from the web interface and that's it ?
Have you flashed / updated a zyxel and any suggestions you may have ? 

Thanks so much for your prompt responses.

Comment: @rihaturn it's always a good idea to reset configuration after a firmware upgrade.